# Grafana 8.0: Alerting for Table Panel (Custom MySQL Query)

Tags: monitoring, grafana, grafana-alerts

I'm using Grafana v8.0.5 and trying to build a panel based on MySQL Datasource using a custom select query. My requirement is to alert me whenever the rows count is more than 5. I tried so many things to make it work but had no luck. Could someone help me achieve this requirement?

Query:

```
SELECT `id`, 
    `org_id`, 
    `profile_name`,
    `command`, 
    `ip_port`,
    `run_status`, 
    `total_records`, 
    `total_records_written`, 
    `start_datetime`, 
    `completed_datetime`,
    TIMEDIFF(`completed_datetime`, `start_datetime`) AS total_sync_time
    FROM 
    `logdb-dev`.`process_table` WHERE `run_status` = 'failed' AND DATE(`start_datetime`) = CURDATE()
    ORDER BY `org_id` ASC;
```